# How to link multiple ViewControllers to a NavigationController in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When I tried adding a view controller to my navigation controller, it worked perfectly fine... But when I connected the first view controller to a second one through a custom segue, it didn't link the second ViewController to the NavigationController

[image]

As you can see, the third ViewController isn't connected to the NavigationController and doesn't have the navigation bar.

Here is everything in the SegueClass

```
@implementation SegueFromRight
```

(void) perform {

```
UIViewController *src = self.sourceViewController;
UIViewController *dst = self.destinationViewController;
CATransition *transition = [[CATransition alloc] init];
CAMediaTimingFunction *timeFunc = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

transition.duration = 0.25;
transition.timingFunction = timeFunc;
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;

[src.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey: kCATransition];

[src.navigationController pushViewController: dst animated: false];
```

}

@end

Is there anything missing I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have created a custom segue. Interface Builder has no way of knowing that this will be the equivalent of a push (show) segue, so it doesn't display the navigation bar by default. But this is just a cosmetic matter; how the scene is displayed in Interface Builder is no significance for what will actually happen at runtime.

If you want to see the navigation bar in Interface Builder, just ask for it; in the Attributes inspector for this view controller, change Top Bar -> Inferred to a visible navigation bar type.

If you need navigation items, just start by adding a Navigation Item directly to this scene.

Comment: It is _also_ the case that your custom segue is incorrect; this is not how to make a custom transition animation. But that's another matter, separate from the question you asked.